# Cannot delete EXE after stopping the application

Tags: windows, electron, nw.js

It looks like some executables do not shut down correctly on Windows. After stopping the application, and deleting the corresponding exe file, it immediately pops up again in the folder. I have to wait for some time (sometimes even minutes) until I can really remove it. Is there any reason/solution for this strange behavior?

This is very annoying, because I'm creating a release directory with a batch script, which previously removes the release directory in case it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason, thanks to this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/338567/why-cant-i-delete-some-exe-files/521349#521349

For some really really crazy (Microsoft internal) reasons you must have the "**Application Experience service**" enabled!!! God knows why! On German installations the service is called "**Anwendungserfahrung**". On my machine it was disabled. As soon as I enabled it, I was able to delete executable files immediately after terminating the EXE/programm!

I hope this post prevents others from going crazy like I did! ;-)